# What will happen to mDPM.lockNow(); if there is no security pin on android device?

Tags: android, device-admin

If a user has not put a security pin on her device, and my app even if it has device admin privileges sends a mDPM.lockNow(); to remote lock the mobile, what will happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will just lock the device! The user can simple unlock normally.

> mDPM.lockNow()

is only to lock the device (regardless of the fact that PIN exists or not)

Comment: No..I implemented it, and it won't.